# Migrating Hyper-V hosted sharepoint servers to a new domain

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I have one Windows server 2012 Hyper-V server which hosts 3 Sharepoint servers and 3 servers with SQL server for Dev, Test, and Prod. We are moving to a new domain, however, we want to keep the existing setup. We do not want to setup a new hyper-v server in the new domain.

Can I migrate the hosted servers to the new domain then migrate the hyper-v server to the new domain.

Yes, I'm aware that best practice would be to set up a new hyper-v host in the new domain and setup the new hosted servers in the new domain and restore the content databases on the new hosted servers and restore share to the new servers but I'm running out of time so I don't have this option at the moment. The old and new domains have a trust setup between them. The user account in prod will be the same except for the domain name.

1. I plan to do backups of sharepoint and the sharepoint content databases.
2. Change the sharepoint services accounts to use the local service or network account.
3. Join the servers to the new domain, only question here is should I do the Hyper-v host last in this process?
4. Migrate the users using MoveSPUser in PowerShell

Any suggestions/comments?

Answer (score 0):

The technical necessary steps have already been described, e.g. [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117901/migrating-sharepoint-farm-from-one-domain-to-another) and [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/26769/move-sharepoint-to-new-domain). It might technically be possible to move a SharePoint-Server from one domain to another, **but it's not supported**! I believe you won't find anyone here giving you an indulgence for your plan.

Your decision is like a false friend. Your way seems to be easier. But you will find a lot of moving parts not working after migration. One example is [UserProfileService](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/203948/how-to-move-sharepoint-2013-from-one-ad-to-another). You will waste tons of time troubleshooting error-by-error-by-error-by-error.

My recommendation: Follow the supported way. Set up a new farm. Move ServiceApplications, customizations and content.

Hyper-V and SharePoint don't know each other. As long as you do not break the Hyper-V Host during Domain-Migration, SharePoint doesn't care when you move it.

Comment: You are right. A wise man learns from the experience from others. I will use the supported way. Thanks for the reminder.